# Unable to use composition (embedded class) in Where Queries

Tags: grails, grails-orm

It seems to be a bug, but before submitting a Jira, I want to make sure I'm not misusing Were Queries.

I'm trying to use [Where Queries](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries) to filter a simple [Composition](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#gormComposition) attribute.

```
Family.where { address.number == 1 }
```

where address is a composition mapped in my Family domain class. When running this piece of code I'm getting a "NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'javaClass' on null object" raised inside "grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.methodMissing(DetachedCriteria.groovy:1136)"

It is probably not a mapping issue, since the alternative [Detached Criteria](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#detachedCriteria) solution is working just as expected:

```
new DetachedCriteria(Family).build {     eq 'address.number', 1 }
```

Isn't composition attributes supported by Where Queries or should I submit a Jira for that?

Comment: Which version of Grails is being used?

Comment: Just noted that the same syntax is used in association mapped queries without issues. It's a problem exclusive to compositions.